# I stored the parent document in variable and want to query that variable to find particular subdocuments that satisfy the query in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I stored user in "user" variable using this query

```
const user = await UserModel.findById({_id : req.userID});
```

This user has array of projects.

for example:

```
user = {
username : 'Alex',
age : 40,
project : [
{
clientname : "Faateh",
payment : 500,
date : 2021 , 21 , 01
},
{
clientname : "Ahsan",
payment : 700,
date : 2021 , 21 , 01
},

]
}
```

I want to get only those projects with clientname == "Ahsan" using query on this "user" variable. How do i do it? Please help

Answer (score 2):

For fetching users, having client name as "Ahsan"

```
// shell query
db.getCollection("users").find({"project.clientname": "Ahsan"})

// Mongoose query
await UserModel.find({"project.clientname": "Ahsan"})
```

For fetching users with matching project details, having client name as "Ahsan"

```
// shell query
db.getCollection("users").find({"project": {"$elemMatch": {"clientname": "Ahsan"}}}, {"username": 1,  "project": {"$elemMatch": {"clientname": "Ahsan"}}})

// Mongoose query
await UserModel.find({"project": {"$elemMatch": {"clientname": "Ahsan"}}}, {"username": 1,  "project": {"$elemMatch": {"clientname": "Ahsan"}}})
```

Comment: I have gotten access to the UserModel collection but now I want the particular project from the array of objects of the project that satisfies the query. How can be this done in denormalization? I can also arrange a google meet in case you want to describe it in detail .Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ahsan https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815998/8130763 this should help.
If you still want to reach out, give me a ping on twitter.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching users, having client name as "Ahsan" in denormalized way

```
// shell query
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{"$unwind": "$project"}, {"$project": {"_id": "$_id", "username": "$username", "age": "$age", "clientname": "$project.clientname", "payment": "$project.payment", "date": "$project.date"}}])

// Mongoose query
await UserModel.aggregate([{"$unwind": "$project"}, {"$project": {"_id": "$_id", "username": "$username", "age": "$age", "clientname": "$project.clientname", "payment": "$project.payment", "date": "$project.date"}}])
```